# Want to sum using if or using case

Tags: sql-server, if-statement, case

I have a table contains the following:

- invoice id
- invoice type
- Sales Price

I want a SQL query to show this information:

```
invoice id    invoice type    Sales Price   
-----------------------------------------
1                  s              500
2                  p              400
3                  s              300
```

I want to sum (Sales Price) when invoice type = 's' - sum (Sales Price) 
when invoice type = 'p'

Using if or case in SQL Server

Comment: how can i show the result in another column ?

Comment: i want the result

Comment: i want the result when type = 's' sum of all sales price - when type = 'p' sum of all sales price

Comment: `i want sql query to show like :` is that example desirable output? If so, what is source data ?

Comment: and show the result in another column

Comment: I've taken a guess at what you want in an answer below. It would help if you added your expected results to your question, in a table layout. It may seem  obvious from your side of things what you want ... but not from the other side!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
select sum(
           case
               when invoice_type = 's' then sales_price
               when invoice_type = 'p' then sales_price * -1
               else null
           ) as NetSales
from MyTable
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in 2 virtual steps: that is, select the records you want, and then sum them.

This is easily done is a subquery as follows:

```
SELECT sum("Sales Price")
FROM (SELECT "Sales Price" FROM whatever WHERE "invoice type"='p') sq;
```

The `sq` at the end is a table alias, and only necessary to satisfy the requirements of sub queries.

By the way, you probably realise that spaces in column names are going to cause problems. I have enclosed the offending column names in double quotes (`"`), which is the standard. MSSQL also uses the square brackets notation, but double quotes are better.

The string (`'p'`), on the other hand is in single quotes.